# What is the Windows batch equivalent of "fuser -k <folder>"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, kill-process, fuser

I have a Unix shell script which will kill any process that is accessing a folder:

```
fuser -k ..\logs\*
```

Is there a Windows batch script equivalent to this? I am aware of TASKKILL but I'm not sure if it will do what I need. Does anyone know if this is possible with Windows shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with built-in tools (there is nothing that can enumerate handles), but you can use the Sysinternals [Handle tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) to get a list of the PIDs that have open handles on a file. You can then parse the output with `FOR /F` and use `TASKKILL` to end the processes.

Example:

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=3" %i in ('handle ..\logs\') do taskkill /pid %i
```

`skip=4` skips the copyright information in Handle's output and `tokens=3` picks out the PID from each line of output. The rest are self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It needs to be done entirely in Windows shell with no other tools as I need to deploy this to many machines which I cannot install things on. I didn't think it was possible with just plain shell either so I'll have to convince my team to install something like this on the machines.

Comment: @Matt: Note that Handle (and any other tool that can do this) must run with administrative privileges.

Answer (score 2):

I found a `fuser` for Windows. Check [this link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fuserforwin32/) to Sourceforge:

> Many would ask, "why not use `handle.exe` from SysInternals?"
>
> While being a truly excellent utility (as all of SysInternals stuff
>   is), it falls short -- at least for me -- for a couple of reasons:
>
> 1. It does filename pattern matching. I need it to do exact file matches with partial input. For example, when I'm in the `C:\TMP` directory, and I'm checking on a file named `out.dat`, I want it to see if the file `C:\TMP\OUT.DAT` is being used without having to type full path in. I think even if you type in the full path for  handle.exe, it will still do pattern matching.
> 2. `handle.exe` seems to always exit 0. For scripting purposes, I need
>      it to exit 1 if the file is not being used, but 0 if it is. This is
>      very useful in scripts.